# Lock acquistion on static members within a Java Class

Tags: java, concurrency, static-members, synchronized

I am currently resolving a performance degradation issue due to heavy lock contention. I am considering "Lock splitting" to resolve this issue.

The skeletal usage pattern is ::

CURRENT USAGE ::

```
public class HelloWorld{

   public static synchronized method1(){
       //uses resource 1
   }
   public static synchronized method2(){
        //uses resource 2
   }

}
```

MY APPROACH ::

since `method1()` and `method2()` does not use the same resource, I am thinking of splitting the locks. As of now, they both contend for the Class lock since they are both static synchronized. I am thinking of changing it to ::

```
public class HelloWorld{

   **private static Object resr1Lock = new Object();**

   public static method1(){
       synchronized(resrc1Lock){
            //uses resource 1
       }
   }

   **private static Object resr2Lock = new Object();** 
   public static method2(){
        synchronized(resrc2Lock){
             //uses resource 2
        }
   }

}
```

Will they now contend for the "Class Lock" or `resr1Lock`/`resrc2Lock` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. It indeed boosted the performance :-) [by nearly 20x]. Another compelling case study to analyze synchronization patterns in any application

Comment: Why use synchronization at all since method1() and method2() does not use a shared resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will now contend for the 2 objects "resr1Lock"/"resrc2Lock. It will work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

They won't contend for a lock on the `Class` object anymore so yes this will solve that problem.